# adb uninstall failed Failure [DELETE_FAILED_OWNER_BLOCKED]

Tags: android, adb

I was trying to uninstall an app which showed:

> Uninstalling unsuccessful This app is required by your device administrator

but it does not show on the device admins. When I used adb to uninstall it gave the error `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_OWNER_BLOCKED]`.

Answer (score 2):

You might have locked the app using the system’s app locker, then you cannot uninstall the app. REMOVE the lock for that app and just uninstall.

Comment: Let me tell you what happened- I locked the app using the system app lock then one day I uninstalled the app then after a few days I reinstalled the app at that time it in the app lock settings it was showing that the app is not locked but it was actually locked. I think it is locked internally because of the previous locking and now the app lock has no control of it whatsoever. Do you have any way I can unlock it?